# Resolve application service spent 1 second

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

We use abp in a really product for user. And there is api, it's so easy, but the response time for it is about 1 second. We think it shouldn't be, then we investigate it, found the execution time for the application service method is about 100 ms, and resolve the application service spent about 1 second.

We use IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(thisAssembly) for register.

Following screenshot is from the log file for investigation:
[image]

My questions are:

1. why the resolver spent so much time?
2. What's the correct way to fix this issue.

Comment: Inject only the services you need.

Comment: @aaron, yes,before asked, I have already removed all unnecessary  services, but it's a core application service, it uses much services for business.

Comment: A core service should not use many business services. If you inject many services, then obviously it takes a longer time to resolve all of them.

Comment: 1) Your application service can use many domain service's and also each domain service can use another services and everyone must be resolved, that's why it takes so much time.
2) Try to implement lazy loading and resolve only needed services not all of them.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14042581/7877686) may help you. You can resolve your services only before usage, so resolving you appservice will speed up.

Comment: Yes, thanks! We have changed the resolve to per request. its so fast now. before it spent about 1 second, now it is 100 ms. And as your suggestion, we are going to improve it further more to use lazy loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before, we use default DependencyLifeStyle as Transient,  and we make some changes to set DependencyLifeStyle to per request. And the resolve is so fast now.

The code changes as below:

```
public override void PreInitialize()
{
    IocManager.IocContainer.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += Kernel_ComponentRegistered;
}
private void Kernel_ComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler)
{
    foreach (var interceptor in interceptors)
    {
        if (interceptor.Key.IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation))
        {
            handler.ComponentModel.Interceptors.Add(new InterceptorReference(interceptor.Value));
        }
    }   
    if (handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.Assembly.FullName.Contains(".Domain"))
    {
        if (handler.ComponentModel.LifestyleType == LifestyleType.Transient)
        {
            IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
            Component
                .For(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation)
                .ImplementedBy(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation)
                .LifestyleCustom<MsScopedLifestyleManager>()
                .IsDefault()
                .Named($"{key}-1")
                );
        }
    }
}
```